# How can Handlebars render a flat JSON object

Tags: javascript, handlebars.js

This question should be relatively simple. I have a collection of flat objects of key-value pairs I would like to render. For my example, I receive a collection of states defined like this:

```
var an_array=[
{AK:"Alaska"},
{WA:"Washington"},    
];
```

And I compile a Handlebars template thus:

```
var source   = $("#src").html();
var template = Handlebars.compile(source);
$("body").append( template(an_array) );
```

The template is not rendering the array:

```
<script type='text/template' id='src'>
<ul>
{{#each .}}
<li>{{@key}}</li>
{{/each}}
</ul>    
</script>
```

From www.handlebars.js:

> For object iteration, use {{@key}} instead:

That's pretty much it. I've written a jsfiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/eggmatters/yMasE/

I have several large arrays being returned from the server and I would like to render those objects as they are instead of reformatting them etc.

Comment: You first have to iterate the array, then to enumerate the contained objects before you can use `{{@key}}` I think

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So for this particular situation, the smoothest way is probably to write a custom iterator. I updated your fiddle, fixed a couple of breaking errors, and added a list iteration helper that achieves what you are after.

```
Handlebars.registerHelper('list', function(ctx, opts) {
  var res = ''
  ctx.forEach(function(obj){
    var key = Object.keys(obj);
    var data = {key: key, val: obj[key]}
    res += opts.fn(obj, { data: data });
  });
  return res;
});

var an_array = [{AK:"Alaska"}, {WA:"Washington"}];
var source = $("#src").html();
var template = Handlebars.compile(source);
$("body").append(template(an_array));
```

Using this iterator, you could update your template to look like this and it will render correctly:

```
<ul>
  {{#list .}}
    <li>{{@key}}: {{@val}}</li>
  {{/list}}
</ul>
```

**Live Example:**
http://jsfiddle.net/yMasE/2/

The way that custom iterators work in handlebars is a little confusing, but you can find some details here: http://handlebarsjs.com/block_helpers.html

Hope this helps!

Comment: What an excellent answer from a really, really smart and attractive guy.

Comment: hahaha wtf kevin how did you even find this? ARE YOU STALKING ME?

Comment: Haha. It was at the top of the homepage.

Comment: Whew, that's just what I needed. Thanks!

Comment: BTW, This was a huge help in following the iteration of the array above. Our client-side is run on Backbone and served by Ruby. The Handlebars compilation is done by the server and sent to the client and is very difficult to debug. Writing a custom iterator like this at least allows you to know what handlebars is doing. As it turns out, our each method was overridden to accept Backbone collections. Some parsing on that side of things and it was all swell. The custom iterator "registered helper" is a nice tool though and I've already implemented it elsewhere